# Is a moving target harder for a PRNG to guess than a static one? How much harder?

Tags: random, prng

Say we have some Pseudo Random Number Generator with a period significantly larger than its range of possible values that is trying to guess a number we have chosen. Can we increase the average number of tries required for the PRNG to guess our number by changing the number we have chosen after each guess of the PRNG?

My understanding is that your typical PRNG is of equal-distribution and includes all numbers in the range it provides numbers on. Thus over the period of the PRNG we'd be guaranteed to have the PRNG eventually guess any static number we could choose. But what effect does this have on the chances of such a thing happening in any practical length of time?

Comment: I thought about asking this on Math.SE, but this is as much a question about the nature of PRNGs as it is one of probability in my eyes.

Comment: If the PRNG is good, it should not make a difference. In my understanding choosing a random number should ideally be an independent event and therefore it would not matter if the "target" is always the same or changes constantly (if changing it is also an independent event). Given for example a range of 1..10 (inclusive) the (perfect) PRNG's chance will always be 1/10 to hit the right number. If one can however make an educated guess about the next random number from the PRNG, and chooses the "target" accordingly it will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions for choosing the 'Target' are random, then, no a moving target is not harder for a PRNG to guess than a static one.

Previous events do not change the outcome of a current event, it's the gamblers paradox.